# Is there any problem with this use of using extension methods to automatically convert textbox text for winforms UI

Tags: c#, extension-methods, implicit-conversion

I did the following because:
a) I am forcing myself to use newer c# language features (or ones I never used before)
b) I am tired of typing out conversion code every time a text box holds a non-string value

So I came up with:

```
public static class MyExt
{
    public static MyTextBox Auto(this TextBox tb)
    {
        return new MyTextBox(tb);
    }
}
public class MyTextBox
{
    private TextBox _textBox;
    public MyTextBox(TextBox t)
    {
        _textBox = t;
    }
    public static implicit operator string(MyTextBox o)
    {
        return o._textBox.Text;
    }
    public static implicit operator int(MyTextBox o)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(o._textBox.Text);
    }
}
```

Then if I have to pass a text box value somewhere that needs an int:

```
var a = new UnitCountsForm(campaign_NumberTextBox.Auto());
```

QUESTION: have I gone off the deep end or is does this seem like a reasonable use of extension methods combined with implicit operators?

Comment: is there any reason why you can not pass into UnitCountsForm a MyTextBox object? Is this just cause you want to use Extension Mehtods?

Comment: didn't think of it - i guess i wanted to limit the reach of the custom class. My goal is to pass a text box to a function expecting something else and have it just work - and since i can't override text box in this case, the extension method is how I wrap it.

Comment: +1 for originality. But I, personaly, would avoid use it like this, cause Extension methods, by me, are good in case when you have not access to source, or can not change it for mln reaons, here it creates more confusion. Much simplier and clear just pass the object you need, so MyTextBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you decide to go ahead with this, I would suggest that you not use extension methods. As somebody else said, the primary use of extension methods is when you don't have the source. In your case, you can replace the extension method with a static factory method inside of `MyTextBox`. Or just eliminate the idea altogether and just write:

```
var mytb = new MyTextBox(tb);
```

I wouldn't recommend even that, though. I think the code you're writing is an unnecessary complication for at best a marginal gain.

One problem with that code is that it doesn't take possible errors into account. For example, your implicit conversion to `int` is going to fail of the textbox doesn't contain a valid integer. There's no simple way to modify the conversion operator to accommodate the error checking. I suppose you could write something like:

```
public static implicit operator int(MyTextBox o)
{
    int val;
    if (int.TryParse(o_textBox.Text, out val))
    {
        return val;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

But then you can't tell the difference between the user entering "-1" and the user entering "xyzzy".

And there's the further complication of validating the values. Converting to an integer is only the first step. You'll also want to make sure that number entered is within the expected bounds.

If you put those requirements together, the idea of writing some convoluted code to give you the integer representation of a textbox's value--if it's a valid integer--seems like a whole lot more work than it's worth.

Comment: so I take it you'd frown on my masterpiece here :) _bindingSource.Filter = "Publisher like '%{0}%'".xFormat(text.IfNullOrWhiteSpace("*"));